# How to use curl command to downlad a file in bitbucket using python

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess.call() to download a file from bitbucket in python.

This curl command works fine when I am running from CMD.

```
curl -O outputpath -u username bitbucketlinktoRawfile
```

This writes the content to the desired output directory.

However when tried to use the same with python subprocess, it fails.

```
import subprocess
args = ["curl","-O","outputpath","-u","username","bitbucketlinktoRawfile"]
subprocess.call(args=args)
```

I get some html on output console.

Comment: Make sure you use the full path when specifying outputpath